# Why does calling .join() on a Python multiprocessing child process attempt to close the IDLE shell?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-idle

The following python script:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f():
    return None

def main():
    print('create')
    p = mp.Process(target=f)
    print('start')
    p.start()
    print('join')
    p.join()
    print('done')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Produces the following output in Python IDLE:

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan 30 2020, 09:44:41) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
===================== RESTART: /home/user/Desktop/test.py =====================
create
start
join
```

Followed by an (unexpected!) GUI prompt "Your program is still running! Do you want to kill it?"

Any clue what's going on here? I know printing from child processes is complicated in IDLE, but this seems unrelated.

Note that running the same code from the terminal gives "normal" output, and exits normally:

```
[user@localhost Desktop]$ python test.py 
create
start
join
done
[user@localhost Desktop]$ python --version
Python 3.7.6
[user@localhost Desktop]$
```

At a suggestion from a colleague, I tried adding `mp.set_start_method('spawn')` to the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f():
    return None

def main():
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    print('create')
    p = mp.Process(target=f)
    print('start')
    p.start()
    print('join')
    p.join()
    print('done')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which causes IDLE to behave how I hoped:

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan 30 2020, 09:44:41) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
===================== RESTART: /home/user/Desktop/test.py =====================
create
start
join
done
>>>
```

Comment: You only print from the main process and I get 'done' (when running in IDLE) with 3.7.7, 3.8.2, and 3.9.0a4 on Windows.  Anything older and you are missing recent bug fixes.  IDLE should not be different on other systems.  Run your code without IDLE to get a better idea of where your problem might be.

Comment: Hi @TerryJanReedy! Thanks for looking at this. Running the same code from the same version of python (3.7.6) at the prompt (python test.py in gnome-terminal) works fine (gets to 'done' and exits normally). 3.7.6 is the python version on a fresh install of Fedora 31 from last week, followed by a complete "sudo dnf update". I understand upgrading is desirable, but I bet a lot of Fedora users are also on 3.7.6.

Comment: 3.7.7 is very recent and might still have the same problem on Fedora.  Try `python -m idlelib test.py` in the terminal and then run from the IDLE editor.  Does any exception or error message appear in the terminal?